# Ubuntu 18.04 - recreate 70-snap.core.rules

Tags: networking, 18.04, udev

How can I recreate `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-snap.core.rules`?  I would like to regenerate the MAC addresses on a cloned system.  I have tried the following commands without success:

- `/sbin/udevadm trigger --type=devices --action=add` (seems to cause the system to think for a little bit at least)
- `udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=net`

Rebooting does not generate the file.  It seems that Bionic Beaver does use `70-persistent-net.rules` anymore.  It also seems like `70-snap.core.rules` is not the same thing as `70-persistent-net.rules` as it is 1,062 lines long.